# select an element in jquery which is in another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

developers sorry if I am disturbing you. so let's get into the problem.
and guys please also consider that I am working with nodejs and electronjs.
a simple representation about the directories

```
main-doc
  |---src
       |---Html
       |     |---index.html
       |     |---navbar.html
       |
       |---svg
       |    |---home.svg   
       |
       |---js
            |---jquery-file.js
```

jquery file is imported to index.html to reuse navbar. 
so my jquery code,

```
$(".navbar-container").load("navbar.html")
console.log($(".icon-container")) // shows no element in console
$(".icon-container").load("../svg/home.svg") // icon-container is in navbar.html
```

So I think since icon container is in navbar.html it is not loaded properly when 2nd line
executes. How to load this svg into my code with jquery in this type of situation?

Answer (score 0):

`.load` is `async` in nature. You can watch `on complete function`. and load/work there.

Sample:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Your case:

```
$(".navbar-container").load("navbar.html", () => {
 console.log($(".icon-container")) // shows no element in console
 $(".icon-container").load("../svg/home.svg") // icon-container is in 
 navbar.html
})
```

read doc: https://api.jquery.com/load/#load-url-data-complete